# Python code execute through django shell but not through file

Tags: python, django

I recently installed the python library [riskchanges](https://pypi.org/project/RiskChanges/). Now I created the `test_lib.py` file and try to use the library function as below,

```py
from RiskChanges.load_SHP import loadshp
loadshp(r'F:\SDSS\1. code\data\Country_border.shp', connstr='postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/sdss', lyrName='layer', schema='try')
```

And I tried to run this code from the terminal, (`python test_lib.py`), it shows the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_lib.py", line 2, in <module>
    loadshp(r'F:\SDSS\1. code\data\Country_border.shp',
  File "F:\SDSS\1. code\django\venv\lib\site-packages\RiskChanges\load_SHP.py", line 39, in loadshp
    geodataframe = geopandas.read_file(shpInput)
  File "F:\SDSS\1. code\django\venv\lib\site-packages\geopandas\io\file.py", line 139, in _read_file
    return GeoDataFrame.from_features(
  File "F:\SDSS\1. code\django\venv\lib\site-packages\geopandas\geodataframe.py", line 427, in from_features
    "geometry": shape(feature["geometry"]) if feature["geometry"] else None
  File "F:\SDSS\1. code\django\venv\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\geo.py", line 105, in shape
    return Polygon(ob["coordinates"][0], ob["coordinates"][1:])
  File "F:\SDSS\1. code\django\venv\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py", line 243, in __init__
    ret = geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
  File "F:\SDSS\1. code\django\venv\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py", line 509, in geos_polygon_from_py
    ret = geos_linearring_from_py(shell)
  File "shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx", line 408, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linearring_from_py
ValueError: GEOSGeom_createLinearRing_r returned a NULL pointer
```

If I tried to run the same thing through django shell, it worked fine without any error message,

```sh
>>> python manage.py shell
>>> from RiskChanges.load_SHP import loadshp
>>> loadshp(r'F:\SDSS\1. code\data\Country_border.shp', connstr='postgresql://postgres:admin@localhost:5432/sdss', lyrName='layer', schema='try')
```

Please help me to find out the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

**python manage.py shell** automatically loads the settings from your settings.py

You need to set it in *test_lib.py*. One of the ways is,

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "<your_project>.settings")
import django
django.setup()
```

Comment: Sorry, I still got the same error, this didn't solve my issue